# LWJGL3.1 any GL11 calls will cause a SIGSEGV fault

Tags: java, opengl, segmentation-fault, lwjgl

Here is the error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000137304bab, pid=55750, tid=0x000000000000080b
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [liblwjgl_opengl.dylib+0xcbab]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/leobattle/Desktop/Programming/Java/Minecraft Modding/GLGame/GLGame/hs_err_pid55750.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I am on macOS 10.12 and using Java 8.

Why would it be causing a seg-fault and how do I fix it?

Code:

```
while (GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != true) { 
    GLFW.glfwPollEvents(); 
    GL11.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f); 
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); 
    GL11.glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f); 
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f); 
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f); 
    GL11.glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f); 
    GL11.glEnd(); 
    GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

Comment: This is basically a dump of knowing that signal segv has been sent to your process. There is no way to help or solve your issue without actually knowing what you are doing. Consider using whatever debugger you have available to you. It will most likely show the faulty code.

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?  Are you trying to draw with the old fixed function pipelines?  What version are you setting in your window (assuming GLFW)

Comment: while (GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != true) {
   GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
   
   GL11.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
   GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   
   GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
   GL11.glEnd();
   
   GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
  }

Comment: I was trying to draw with the fixed function just to see something work immediately; I know that you are now meant to draw with shaders. Does macOS just not support those functions anymore?

Comment: Please click "edit" button on your question and add the code there, not here in the comments.

Comment: Edited. Blahblahblah make the comment long enough...

Answer (score 1):

Oops. Solved!I forgot to add GL.createCapabilities();

Answer (score 1):

I see you've answered your question there, but I have a little more insight into what exactly GL.createCapabilities() does.

Once you've created your context with GLFW's glfwMakeContextCurrent(), we only have a context with your window, but some things are still missing.

GL.createCapabilities() does 3 things; loads the native libraries, creates instances of GLCapabilities (which you can use to check a lot of things about your context, for example, compatible extensions) and creates some threads to manage said GLCapabilities.

(Although I haven't tested, I think GL.create() will also solve your problem.)

Obviously, the issue you were encountering was in the fact that the libraries were missing, and that's what gave you the error. That's OK, I got the same error too. Just be sure to call GL.createCapabilities() after a context has been created (and is current) but before any OpenGL calls.

You can read more here: https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL.html